# Changing registry values in C

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, registry

I'm learning C and trying to make an application that will change the login background screen for Windows 7.

I know that I need to change some registry values (instructions to do it without programming here: http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/change-the-windows-7-login-screen-background-image/)

So I know in order to change the value in the registry, I need to create a handle to an open value, and then change it.

This is what I have so far:

```
char* number = 0x00000001; 
HKEY key;

if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Authentication\\LogonUI\\Background"), 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &key) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
    printf("Key location open successful \n");


    if (RegSetValueEx(key, "OEMBackground", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&number, sizeof(DWORD))){
        printf("Key not changed in registry \n");
        printf("Error %d ", GetLastError());
    }

    else{
        printf("Key changed in registry \n");
    }

    RegCloseKey(key);

}

else {
    printf("Unsuccessful in opening key  \n");
    printf("Cannot find key value in registry \n");
    printf("Error: %d ", GetLastError());
}
```

The results I have say that the key is open, and that the value has been changed.  But the value isn't changed.

The value in the registry is currently 0.  I want to change it to 1.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the following changes:

1. `char* number = 0x00000001` is not how to declare a `DWORD`. You want `DWORD value = 0x00000001`. And then pass `(BYTE*)&value` to `RegSetValueEx`.
2. You should check the return value of `RegSetValueEx` against `ERROR_SUCCESS`.
3. You need to add a manifest to your executable. That will ensure that you do not run virtualized. And you will also need to add the `requireAdministrator` option to ensure that the process is elevated.
4. You are probably also being tricked by the registry redirector. Include the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag when calling `RegOpenKeyEx` to [access the 64 bit registry view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx).

The following program should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    DWORD number = 0x00000001; 
    HKEY key;

    if (RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Authentication\\LogonUI\\Background", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &key) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Key location open successful \n");
        if (RegSetValueExW(key, L"OEMBackground", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&number, sizeof(DWORD)) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Key changed in registry \n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Key not changed in registry \n");
            printf("Error %u ", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
        }
        RegCloseKey(key);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Unsuccessful in opening key  \n");
        printf("Cannot find key value in registry \n");
        printf("Error: %u ", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Make sure that you link a proper application manifest to the program with the `requireAdministrator` to ensure elevation.

Comment: Sounds better than my answer, anyway. Especially point 4.  The call says it succeeded, so not likely to be permissions/privileges, 'cos that would have returned 'ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED', (presumably:).

Comment: @MartinJames If the process is virtualized, then it will succeed without elevation. I believe that 1, 3 and 4 are all needed.

Comment: 1. Done
2. ERROR_SUCCESS according to MSDN docs, is what is returned if the method is a success.
3. What's a manifest? Could you elaborate on this bit please.
4. Is that to replace 'KEY_SET_VALUE'? I've put both in using | in between.

Still isn't changed, though.

Comment: I'll upvote if you add one more nitpick. `"OEMBackground"` should really be `TEXT("OEMBackground")`

Comment: The program in my answer works. Paste it verbatim. Learn about application manifests by read the docs on msdn.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I was trying that earlier and it wasn't working, thinking it might have made a difference I got rid of it...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for posting code, I'll have a crack at it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it worked! What's the difference between RegOpenKeyExW and RegOpenKeyEx?

Comment: @Michael I never code for ANSI and always code to the native Unicode API. Even the promise of an upvote won't make me change to use TCHAR.

Comment: @Michael The code will compile no matter what setting is used. Read it again.

Comment: @Michael I pasted the TEXT(...) from the Q. It shouldn't really be there. I think it's good now.

Comment: @Michael our comments crossed!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What you have now makes sense. And I have upvoted it. I was just trying to make sure the code would work. All is good now. I will cleanup my comments in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

'char* number = 0x00000001;' is not an LPBYTE target.  Try char number=1;

Comment: OK, but you specify REG_DWORD, so how about 'DWORD number=1;' or 'unsigned int number=1;'?

Comment: ..and maybe '(LPDWORD)&number'

Comment: Neither of those worked, would I need to change the 'sizeof() part too? If I'm changing the variable of 'number'?

Comment: OK, I'm stuck now.  The types and length seem OK, and the call returns success.  'number' should not change 'cos it's an [in] parameter.  Should have worked:(

Answer (score 0):

Try running the application with Administrator privileges and not straight debugging.

I use this code myself to edit the registry:

```
HKEY hkey;
DWORD disp;
BYTE *b[0x1];
b[0] = 1;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer", REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey);
RegSetValueEx(hkey, L"RPEnabled", 0, REG_BINARY, b, 0x1);
```

Comment: How do I do that? I've tried running it as an application - i.e. not from Visual Studio, but it made no difference.

Comment: If the call had failed 'cos permissions/privileges, it should not have returned ERROR_SCCESS, which it is aparrently doing:(